# Swift dictionary empty after appending elements

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have simple class:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class OWMAPIManager {


    private var params = [String : AnyObject]()

    internal init(apiKey: String) {
        params["APPID"] = apiKey
    }
}
```

And I'm creating new object by this:

```
let weatherApi = OWMAPIManager(apiKey: "myApi key")
```

Problem is that after init method my array Dictionary is still empty. Can You tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it works for me in a Playground, `params` contains the new entry, this code is correct.

Comment: @EricD. I'm trying to run it in iOS9.2. Creating object in viewDidLoad and after this line of code I have empty map. I have tried cleaning project. Still the same.

Comment: I guess this is a scope problem. You should edit your question and show your actual code in situation. We can't guess everything. :)

Comment: @EricD. Hi! I have changed a bit code and now it is working. I have now: `private var params :[String : AnyObject]?` and in initialized i have changed: `self.params = [String:AnyObject]()
        self.params!["APPID"] = apiKey` It is working but now I have to unwrap it everywhere. Any clues why this is working and "proper" solution is not?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have to change the following line, I can't see everything so it is hard to guess but this might be the problem.
Change that:

```
private var params: [String: AnyObject]?
```

Write me if that did it

If you remove the question mark, then it is non optional

Comment: I know, now I have optional var that I'm initializing in init method. I would like not to have optional but my original code is not working. Edit - after cleaning code again and checking print - code is working in original state without optional. Thanks for help.

Comment: Remove the question mark after you declare the variable.

Comment: Which type of is ApiKey?

Comment: I have made it work as in original question code. Without optionals `private var params = [String : AnyObject]()`

Comment: @Anokrize: please don't spread nonsense. Marking an answer as accepted is and always will be *optional*. Question bans are not based on wether or not you marked answers as accepted, they are purely based on the quality of your questions.

Comment: Well I got a question ban and tried everything to remove it but somehow I can not get rid of the question ban @MartijnPieters

Comment: The [help center information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) tells you what you can do. Note that it makes no mention of marking answers as accepted.

Comment: Ok I thought that the system scans if the questions are answered or not. I tried everything from the help center and I also contacted the support but they don't answer me @MartijnPieters

Comment: You'll have to be patient, I'm afraid. If you did your best and improved your questions, eventually you'll come out of the ban.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have initialised your dictionary

Comment: If you look at the question you will see that it is already the case. And if you look at the comments under the question this will be confirmed.